# Docker & Django - what directory does localhost point to?

Tags: docker

I'm completely new to Docker and Django and I'm having trouble getting my Docker app to serve inside Django. Currently, I'm running my docker container with this command:

```
docker run -it --name web -p 8000:8000 --link mysql:db -v ~/directory:/app django
```

where `mysql` and `django` refer to containers defined earlier.

Next, I'm using `manage.py` to make migrations and migrate, then serving with the following command:

```
mod_wsgi-express start-server --reload-on-changes --working-directory /app/voting_project /app/voting_project/voting_project/wsgi.py &
```

When I visit `localhost:8000` in my browser, it successfully renders the HTML template, but the CSS and images which I see locally are missing.

The following errors are logged in the console:
[image]

I've played with the structure of my directories a bit, but I can't seem to get the browser to find anything in `localhost:8000/static` or `localhost:8000/images`.

I'm assuming 8000 is mapping to somewhere weird in my local directories, but I realize this could also be caused by a number of other things. Please let me know if I'm making any obvious mistakes.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a problem with the django configuration better fitting to stackoverflow, and not so much a devops problem.

Check the `settings.py` for the following entries:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    (...)
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

At the end of this file

```
STATIC_ROOT='staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

source **Django manual:** [How to static-files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/)